# How to provide ApolloClient via props rather than context

Tags: react-apollo

I'm gradually incorporating Apollo into a fairly substantial React/Redux app. I prefer not to wrap my React app in `ApolloProvider`for now. I'd like to support multiple `ApolloClient` instances for different GraphQL endpoints and I don't really like the idea of nesting providers (I already use Redux's `Provider`). In general I'm trying to "ease in" to Apollo and add it explicitly in a few specific places. That is my motivation, now here is my question:

It seems reasonable to me to provide an `ApolloClient` instance directly to the `Query` component via props. This way we are explicit about the data source and can support multiple clients. This seems to work:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://w5xlvm3vzz.lp.gql.zone/graphql"
});

...
<Query client={client} variables={...} query={}>
    ...
</Query>
```

My only concern with this approach is I get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find "client" in the context of Query or as passed props. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>
```

Any thoughts on avoiding this error message? I realize using `ApolloProvider` to inject the client is more typical but for my situation I prefer the explicitness and flexibility of passing it as props. It seems to be working but I would like to avoid the console error.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, that shouldn't happen if you're passing it in as a prop. Can you verify that client is actually defined? Also, are there potentially `Mutation` or `Subscription` components that you're using that you don't pass the client to in a similar manner?